# Trying to override the method of laravel passport package by the help autoload psr-4 but does not get expected result

Tags: laravel, autoload

**Composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Laravel\\Passport\\": "app/Override/"  //tried "Passport//" only also
        }
    },
```

I have file **AccessTokenController.php** which lie in vendor\laravel\passport\src\Http\Controllers\ and i create **Override** folder inside **App** directory on where i copied that file and make changes in code
**And finally when i do** :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

i get error as :`Class Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController located in ./app/Override/AccessTokenController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`
seems problem with namespace which i couldn't figure out though trying some of the ways ..
*Anyone can help me ?*

Answer (score 1):

I would simply override the route from within the app as [mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/messi89/489473c053e3ea8d9e034b0032effb1d). No need for the approach you mentioned above.

However, if you want to keep going this route you can try the following.

```json
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
}
"exclude-from-classmap": [
    "Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController"
],
"files": [ 
   "app/Override/AccessTokenController.php"
],
```

Comment: any idea about my approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by including complete namespace of **AccessTokenController.php**.so final code would look like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\":"app/Override/"
        }
    }
```